# In D, what's the difference between a private import and a normal import?

Tags: d

In the D programming language, what is the difference between

```
private import tango.io.File;
```

and

```
import tango.io.File;
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a time when imports were `public` by default; that is, when you imported another module, its contents would not only be visible from within your module but also from any module that imported *your* module.

Eventually, it was changed so that they were `private` by default.

However, there's a few reasons to manually specify `private`:

1. Imports can be made `public` if they're in a `public` context.  For example:

   ```
   public:

   // Lots of stuff

   import blah; // oh no, everyone can see my imports!
   ```
2. DMD teems with import-related bugs.  For example, selective imports are public by default in spite of supposedly being private.  This can cause all sorts of horrible nightmare scenarios where symbols (erroneously) imported publically in one module cause symbols in a completely different module to simply vanish and break your program.

In other words, they're probably `private` in Tango because the devs have worked with DMD for too long to trust it to get this stuff right.

Comment: re pt 2 are you talking about D2 or D1?

Comment: I don't use D2.  That said, I'd be somewhat surprised if D2 doesn't have the same problems; dmd 1.x and dmd 2.x are built from the same source code, just with different pre-processor defines.  Imports haven't really changed between 1.x and 2.x, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It seems import symbols explicitly, those symbols become public in the importing module. For example, module2 `import module1 : Foo`, and module3 `import module1; import module2;` results in conflicted `Foo`. (Here `Foo` is a class name, my dmd version 2.059.)

Answer (score 4):

In D 2.0, `private import` is synonymous with `import`, as opposed to `public import`. By default, imports are private. See the [Modules documentation](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/module.html)

EDIT: By default, imports are private [D 1.0](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/module.html), too.